# cocos2d for iphone touch detection on a sprite

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am using ccTouchesBegan and ccTouchesEnded methods to register touches. Everything was ok until I placed some buttons(ccmenuitems) on my node. now when i place my finger down on a button and then move it to any other place of screen ccTouchesEnded method does not calls. What am I doing wrong? How can I detect touches on a button?

some code:

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: [touches anyObject]];
// here i check if touch is in the right place
if ([self ptInRect:location :CGRectMake(0, center.y - 160, winSize.width, 40)]) {
    dragBeginLocation = location;
}
```

}

```
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: [touches anyObject]];
if (ABS(location.x - dragBeginLocation.x) < 8) {
    NSLog(@"TAP");
} else {
    NSLog(@"SWIPE");
}
```

}

So, when I begin touch on a sprite and release on background I get nothing in console.

Buttons are in CCMenu, which is higher than background.

Comment: I think you will need to post some code..

Comment: is your buttons on another layer of scene?, if so it may higher priority to swallow touches.. put some code u used..